# kml files android programming

Tags: android, kml

I am working with google maps api on android studio trying to show a kml file into my Map.

On My Kml every polygone has son values like this

```
<ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Zonas_VDP21_Marzo_18">
    <SimpleData name="Ciudad">SAN ANTONIO CORONADO</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="Agente">VDP21</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="ZIP">NORESTE</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="PROVINCIA">1</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="GerenciaGe">CMD3</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="ID Bolsa_1">CI277</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="DTA Distri">11104</SimpleData>
</SchemaData></ExtendedData>
```

what i am trying to do is to make every polygone show it's data after i click it. like google maps online do (https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0).

[image: Google Maps Example]

But i can just show the kml layer like this:

[image: Android Map]

this is ok, but i cant click any polygone to access its information this is my code

```
public void DownloadFiles(){

    try {
        URL u = new URL("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXX.kml");
        final InputStream is = u.openStream();
        layer = new KmlLayer(map, is, getApplicationContext());
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {


                    layer.addLayerToMap();
                    layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new KmlLayer.OnFeatureClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFeatureClick(com.google.maps.android.data.Feature feature) {
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,
                                    "Feature clicked: " + feature.getId(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.getMessage();
                }
            }
        });


    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "malformed url error", mue);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "io error", ioe);
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "security error", se);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

keep this on mind:
1. The map is correctly load and created on my app.
2. kml file is correctly downloaded from my webservice.
3. kml file format is correct.

Comment: Your image of the details is part of the product Google Maps. Given that the Google Maps Android API Utility library has examples, where is the example showing that details? I think you need to create that on your own.

Comment: and which one should be the method for that? KmlLayer just has an setOnFeatureClickListener (and it doesnt work)

Comment: The Google Maps Android API Utility library is open source. Make modifications to make it show and behave the way you want: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#custom_info_windows

Answer (score 0):

In KML, you can apply a shared balloon template to all of your features (Placemarks, Points, Lines, Polygons, etc.).  You do this using a shared BalloonStyle cointaining the HTML & CSS for the balloon layout you want, and with variables (eg: $[my_variable]) that pull in the data for the current feature. See the contents of the `<BalloonStyle>` tag in the sample KML below, which uses the sample data you provided.

I'm not sure if that will completely solve your issue when using it on Android, but this is how you would do it in KML, for viewing in Google Earth and Maps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2 https://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/atom-author-link.xsd">
  <Document id="root">
    <name>Polygon Balloon Example</name>
    <open>1</open>

    <Style id="my_style_id">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ff0000ff</color>
        <width>2</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <color>770000ff</color>
        <fill>1</fill>
        <outline>1</outline>
      </PolyStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[
          <html>
          <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <style>
            .rTable {
                display: table;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .rTableBody {
                display: table-row-group;
            }
            .rTableRow {
                display: table-row;
            }
            .rTableCell {
                display: table-cell;
                padding: 3px 10px;
                border: 0px;
            }
            .dataName {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            </style>
          </head>
          <body>
            <h1>$[name]</h1>
            <div class="rTable">
              <div class="rTableBody">
                <div class="rTableRow">
                  <div class="rTableCell"><span class="dataName">$[Zonas/Ciudad/displayName]</span></div>
                  <div class="rTableCell">$[Zonas/Ciudad]</div>
                </div>
                <div class="rTableRow">
                  <div class="rTableCell"><span class="dataName">$[Zonas/Agente/displayName]</span></div>
                  <div class="rTableCell">$[Zonas/Agente]</div>
                </div>
                <div class="rTableRow">
                  <div class="rTableCell"><span class="dataName">$[Zonas/ZIP/displayName]</span></div>
                  <div class="rTableCell">$[Zonas/ZIP]</div>
                </div>
                <div class="rTableRow">
                  <div class="rTableCell"><span class="dataName">$[Zonas/PROVINCIA/displayName]</span></div>
                  <div class="rTableCell">$[Zonas/PROVINCIA]</div>
                </div>
                <div class="rTableRow">
                  <div class="rTableCell"><span class="dataName">$[Zonas/GerenciaGe/displayName]</span></div>
                  <div class="rTableCell">$[Zonas/GerenciaGe]</div>
                </div>
                <div class="rTableRow">
                  <div class="rTableCell"><span class="dataName">$[Zonas/ID Bolsa_1/displayName]</span></div>
                  <div class="rTableCell">$[Zonas/ID Bolsa_1]</div>
                </div>
                <div class="rTableRow">
                  <div class="rTableCell"><span class="dataName">$[Zonas/DTA Distri/displayName]</span></div>
                  <div class="rTableCell">$[Zonas/DTA Distri]</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </body>
          </html>
        ]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>    

    <Schema name="Zonas" id="Zonas_VDP21_Marzo_18">   
      <SimpleField type="string" name="Ciudad">     
        <displayName>Ciudad</displayName>   
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="Agente">     
        <displayName>Agente</displayName>   
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="ZIP">     
        <displayName>ZIP</displayName>   
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="PROVINCIA">     
        <displayName>PROVINCIA</displayName>   
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="GerenciaGe">     
        <displayName>GerenciaGe</displayName>   
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="ID Bolsa_1">     
        <displayName>ID Bolsa_1</displayName>   
      </SimpleField>
      <SimpleField type="string" name="DTA Distri">     
        <displayName>DTA Distri</displayName>   
      </SimpleField>
    </Schema> 

    <Placemark id="myPlace">
      <name>Sample Polygon</name>
      <snippet></snippet>
      <description><![CDATA[description_HTML]]></description>
      <styleUrl>#my_style_id</styleUrl>
      <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Zonas_VDP21_Marzo_18">
        <SimpleData name="Ciudad">SAN ANTONIO CORONADO</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Agente">VDP21</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ZIP">NORESTE</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="PROVINCIA">1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="GerenciaGe">CMD3</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ID Bolsa_1">CI277</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="DTA Distri">11104</SimpleData>
      </SchemaData></ExtendedData>      
      <Polygon>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>0,0,0 0,10,0 10,10,0 10,0,0 0,0,0</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>

  </Document>
</kml>
```